# Short story with male & female main characters. They leave separately and he prepares the colony for her arrival with a colony ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-colonization, terraforming

There are two total characters. A man and a woman.

The man is on a separate ship, and had left 500-1,000 years before to head to a certain planet. He arrives in orbit and sends a myriad of seeds to the surface.
Eventually he goes down and works to fill the planet with animals, and he mines and processes ore and such to prepare for the second ship, which has sleeping colonists.

Over time he dies and is reborn several times.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can [edit] in any more details? Every little bit you are able to remember helps us. Thanks

Comment: This sounds familiar, but I can't think of the title.  It might be by Arthur C. Clarke, but I'm not sure...  I'll try to look in my "library" at home to see if any of those titles spark some more recognition.

Comment: How can the woman be a main character if she is sleeping on a colony ship in space the whole time?

Comment: I finally looked at my stash of books and couldn't find what I was looking for.  Sorry.